# converting tikz to pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I would like to create a graphic with gnuplot for example and import it to latex to implement it in a text. The problem is that its caption, which I created with latex, has a different font, size etc. than the labeling of the axes which were created by gnuplot.

Now I thought I might create an image via gnuplot saved as `tikz`, so that, when I include it in latex, the labeling's font etc., changes to the standards of the rest of my document in latex. At the end I would like to see a PDF format file which contains my text and the graphic with the same font-/ size etc.

Comment: Looks like you are searching for the `standalone` documentclass…

Comment: Why don't you call `gnuplot` from within `tikz`? Then everything should be consistent. Examples for [tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/gnuplot/) and [pgfplots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) (search for gnuplot, or 4th example).

Answer (score 3):

## Example

Plotting the von Neumann entropy of a two-level spin system, which was prepared in a state of superposition.

## Gnuplot code

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

reset
set terminal tikz standalone
set output "entropy.tex"

unset key
set grid
set xrange [0:1]
set samples 1000
set title 'Von Neumann entropy'
set xlabel '$\lambda$'
set ylabel '$S(\lambda)$'

plot -( 1./2. * (1 + sqrt(1-2*x+2*x**2)) *      log( 1./2. * (1 + sqrt(1-2*x+2*x**2)) )         +       1./2. * (1 - sqrt(1-2*x+2*x**2)) *      log( 1./2. * (1 - sqrt(1-2*x+2*x**2)) ) )
```

## LaTeX Output

Compile the produced `entropy.tex` using `pdflatex`. You now get the correct LaTeX fonts.

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this python script, which is very easy to use.
https://github.com/oso/tikz2pdf

I think the README explains most of the part. Say if you have a tikz file myfig.tikz, you just type in terminal

```
tikz2pdf myfig.tikz
```

and a pdf file myfig.pdf will be generated in the same folder. If you want to have the pdf updated once the tikz file is modified, you can use this command:

```
tikz2pdf -ws myfig.tikz
```

I only need to change the default viewer to `open` to use it on a mac, and on a linux machine you can put an alias in your .bashrc

```
alias open=xdg-open
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: Link-only answers are not that helpful. Could you provide more detail in terms of the interface, how one would use it, and perhaps show an example?