# Inserting graph from gnuplot to latex

Tags: graphics, gnuplot, svg

How to insert high quality graph drawn in GNUplot in LaTeX. I am trying to use following method:

1. draw graph in gnuplot
2. saving it as SVG file
3. converting svg into pdf
4. Inserting pdf into latex file

However, I am unable to include greek letters in the SVG file? Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for not exporting directly to PDF using the `pdfcairo` terminal, or using the `cairolatex` terminal?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `latex3` in my point of view

Comment: Note that there is a convenient `gnuplottex` package that allows you to embed gnuplot code directly in your TeX code.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you may want to have a look at the `pgfplots` package, which lets you draw high quality graphs in LaTeX. The main advantage of using the package is that it has a proper interface with LaTeX and lets you define _styles,_ so you can draw graphs in the same consistent style.

Comment: You might be interested in my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141374/10995) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120463/10995).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Look at the tag edits ;-) Torbjorn deleted the `latex3` the same day the question was posted

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: No worries: I did not came back to this question to delete my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to make changes to the image at the `SVG`  stage? If not then you could simply export your graph as a `PDF` following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004797/gnuplot-pdf-output). However, you may prefer to use `GNUplot`'s `epslatex` output mode an input the figure that way, this would give you much better control over the text elements of the graph since the are controlled by `LaTeX`. Instruction for doing this can be  found [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/files/tutorial.pdf).

Comment: Yes, I need to make changes to the image at the SVG state

Comment: What changes do you need to make, are these related to the textual or image elements of the figure? Either way you may want to look at the `LaTeX` terminal mode as you should be able to make the changes you want to either the `EPS` or the `tex` file generated. Why exactly are you unable to include greek in your current method? If you are using `inkscape` you can insert any `unicode` character.

Comment: `Cairolatex` and/or `epslatex` or even the `tikz` terminal should be far better than the `latex` terminal. See ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.pdf for examples.

Comment: @John sorry I meant `epslatex`, will edit now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really want svg: In newer versions of inkscape you can export the text separately. That is you get a .pdf file that only contains the image-information and a .pdf-tex that contains latex-commands to overlay the text. The big advantage then is that you have full access to latex functionalities. You could for example say in gnuplot

```
set xlable '$\sum\xi^\Xi$'
set term svg ....; set out 'mysvg.svg'
#plot something
```

and then you go to inkscape or use console

```
inkscape mysvg.svg --export-pdf mypdf.pdf --export-latex
```

which also creates mypdf.pdf_tex and then say

```
\begin{figure}
\input{mypdf.pdf_tex}
\caption{Stackexchange is really helpful}
\end{figure}
```

in your latex document.

One problem with this approach is that you might get into situations where you need your figure to be self-contained (some journals are ridiculuos for example). For this purpose I have written a tiny bash script that sets up a new .tex document with the figure in it and compiles it so that the result is a pdf with the text on it. (kind of like the old fig2pdf but with svg s)

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, if you need to make changes after plotting, then SVG is an acceptable solution. If not, PDF, or better still: gnuplot's **epslatex** terminal will be best. See [here](http://psung.blogspot.se/2007/03/gnuplot-plots-in-latex.html), and if you can have also look at the explanation of this in the book "Gnuplot in Action", by P. Janert.